# Create a progressbar for the next commands

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, rsync

I am developing backup script on linux (using bash linux [.sh]), and I need create a dialog (with command dialog) with progress bar to show to client status of the commands.

For example, I want a dialog box like:

**Title:** Installing required commands.

**Dialog text:** 
We are installing required commands for Backup system.
Installing sshpass command...
(progress bar go here)

The same I want apply for the next commands:

```
sudo apt-get install sshpass #(used for example)
sudo apt-get install rsync
sudo mkdir
sudo rsync -aAXv
```

Here example for I want make:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzlXW.gif

I using ubuntu desktop 16.04 LTS x64.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? A Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]